# Visualization data inserted in the webpage is not properly indented and not appearing at desired position

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, visualization

I think the chart I have added should come after the heading **Implementation of SVG work**, but it is visible at the end. I have assigned the div section where it should be inserted. I want my code to show this graph where I have used it that is after **Implementation of SVG Work** and before **Feature Work**.

[image: This is how it looks]
**------------**

I am pasting the code I have written.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
          <head>
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">



                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
                  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.layout.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
                  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <style type="text/css">
       text {
        font-size: 11px;
      }
      </style>

          </head>

          <body>
              <div class="container" >
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="col-md-4 img-responsive"><img src="img/e2.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100" width="100"></div>


                        <div class="col-md-4" >
                          <h1 ></h1>

                      </div>


                  <div class="col-md-4" >
                          <h1 >Plan Your Courses</h1>

                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <h2>Implementation of SVG Work</h2>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
             var dataset = [ 25, 7, 5, 26, 11, 8, 25, 14, 23, 19,
                      14, 11, 22, 29, 11, 13, 12, 17, 18, 10,
                      24, 18, 25, 9, 3 ];


                 //Width and height
                      var w = 500;
                      var h = 100;
                      var barPadding = 1;   // <-- New!


                 //Create SVG element
                      var svg = d3.select("body")
                      .append("svg")
                      .attr("width", w)
                      .attr("height", h);

                  // GENERATING RECTANGLES AND MAKING BAR CHART

                       svg.selectAll("rect")
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .append("rect")
                     .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                          return i * (w / dataset.length);
                      })
                     .attr("y", function(d) {
                          return h- (d*5);
                     })
                     .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
                     .attr("height", function(d) {
                          return d*5;
                     })
                     .attr("fill", function(d) {
                          return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
                      });

              // APPENDIND TEXT INTO THE BAR CHART

                  svg.selectAll("text")
                     .data(dataset)
                     .enter()
                     .append("text")
                     .text(function(d) {
                          return d;
                     })
                     .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                          return i * (w / dataset.length) + 3;
                     })
                     .attr("y", function(d) {
                          return h - (d * 4) + 10;
                     })
                     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                     .attr("font-size", "11px")
                     .attr("fill", "white");


              </script>

                      </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <h2>Feature Work</h2>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
                          <h3>Appify</h3>
                          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <img class="img-responsive"  src="http://placehold.it/555x300">
                          <h3>Appify</h3>
                          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the place where you are appending the svg element. Right now it is in body so being added at the end of the body. Change it.

Answer (score 2):

I does not matter, where you place your script code, but where the svg node is added. If you do `d3.select("body").append("svg")`, the svg node will be appended to the body node as the last child node and consequently the graphics appears at the very end.

One possibility to position the svg node in the right place, is by inserting a dedicated container-div like this:

```
<body>
  <div><!-- before svg --></div>
  <div id="svg-container"><!-- you want your svg here --></div>
  <div><!-- after svg --></div>
</body>
```

You can then insert the svg node with `d3.select("div#svg-container").append("svg")`.

Since you have already a respective div element with the sub heading in it, you can just make it identifiable with an id-attribute. It seems as if your current classes ("col-md-12") are in fact IDs.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I just didn't paid attention where exactly I was appending the SVG element.